# Mutiple images in one line CSS + Div

Tags: css

Used this code around every image

```
<div class="side-by-side"> <a href="http://example.com ....>  (include ALL the code for the image here) </div>
```

This is the CSS snippet

```
.side-by-side { float: left; margin-right: 5px }
```

It works... I mean images are on one line
But unfortunately the images align left, and I want them centered, all together.

Comment: So remove  the floats and use `text-align:center` on the container

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your images in a div and set the `text-align:center;` then you dont need the extra div to wrap your a tags in you can just style the a tag itself. Like so:

```
<div class="centered-content">
  <a href="#" class="side-by-side">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="side-by-side">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="side-by-side">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

And Css:

```
.centered-content{
  text-align:center;
}
.side-by-side{
  margin-right:5px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Flexbox to do it. Wrap your `div` in a container

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="side-by-side"> <a href="http://example.com"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .container {
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center;
}
```